# emulating 'placeholder' attribute of HTML5 for IE

Tags: jquery, html, placeholder

I know there are many questions with full of answers for this, but my case is a little different. I'm trying to emulate the exact behavior of 'placeholder' attribute, which is-

**1. Text remains as it is onfocus**

**2. Cursor moves to the start of the text**

**3. Text is unselectable either by mouse's click-drag or by keyboard's shift-arrow**

**4. Text disappears on keypress or on paste**

and 5th one is obviously 'this' text is removed on submit.

I think I'm done with '1' and 1st part of '4' but '2', '3', and 2nd part(onpaste) of 4th still remains a problem... :(

My jquery so far....

```
$(document).ready(function(){
if(!Modernizr.input.placeholder){
    $('[placeholder]').keypress(function() {
      var input = $(this);
      if (input.val() == input.attr('placeholder')) {
        input.val('');
        input.removeClass('placeholder');
      }
    }).keyup(function() {
      var input = $(this);
      if (input.val() == '' || input.val() == input.attr('placeholder')) {
        input.addClass('placeholder');
        input.val(input.attr('placeholder'));
      }
    }).keyup();
    $('[placeholder]').parents('form').submit(function() {
      $(this).find('[placeholder]').each(function() {
        var input = $(this);
        if (input.val() == input.attr('placeholder')) {
          input.val('');
        }
      })
    });
    $('[placeholder]').focus(function() {
    var input = $(this);
    if (input.val() == input.attr('placeholder')) {
              //move the cursor to beginning
              //move the text unselectable
    }
});
}
});
```

For 2nd and 3rd I've tried working around with onselectstart, setCursorPosition, setSelectionRange, etc... but nothing seemed to work as intended. And for the onpaste I thought to bind it with keypress but now donno what to do bcoz at w3schools there is no such event attrubute: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_eventattributes.asp although at MSDN it shows up: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms536955%28v=vs.85%29.aspx .

So please help!

Comment: I've been trying to achieve all of those points in [Placeholders.js](https://github.com/jamesallardice/Placeholders.js) and have had some limited success. If you manage any better, feel free to open a pull request on GitHub!

Answer (score 0):

I suggest a different approach, using CSS change the position of the label to be shown over the input and from JS, only on IE, make the label visible.

```
(function ($) {

    $.fn.placeholder = function (options) {

        var options = $.extend({}, $.fn.placeholder.defaults, options);

        //show <label @for> for IE 
        if ($.browser.msie && $.browser.version < 10)
        {
            return this.each(function () {

                var $this = $(this);            

                $("label[for=" + $this.attr('id') + "]").show();

                //hide placeholder on focus
                $this.focus(function () {
                    if (!$.trim($this.val())) {
                        $("label[for=" + $this.attr('id') + "]").hide();
                    };
                });

                //show placeholder if the input is empty
                $this.blur(function () {
                    if (!$.trim($this.val())) {
                        $("label[for=" + $this.attr('id') + "]").show();
                    };
                });
            });
        }
    };

    //expose defaults
    $.fn.placeholder.defaults = {

    };
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: I'm afraid if I can have a go with this approach for 'label' are already being used for few other functionality(commenting,sorting,etc..)...but thanks for it.